# PHP -- How do I extract a substring + X number of characters before it?

Tags: php, string, capture

I asked a question yesterday that was superbly answered by several people (thank you).

New question :)

I want to extract a unique substring within a string, but also capture X number of characters before it.  Is there any function that allows this?

---

I just found strrpos() -- this might do it.

Comment: Fooling around with preg_split, but doesn't look like I can "rewind" X characters from a given position.  There's no cut-and-dry function to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a built in to do this, but this should do the trick:

```
function subbef($str, $sub, $bef)
{
    $pos = strpos($str, $sub);
    if ($pos === false || $pos < $bef) {
        return false;
    }
    return substr($str, $pos - $bef, strlen($sub) + $bef);
}
```

Usage is like:

```
subbef('test string here', 'string', 3); //"st string"
```

Comment: Thanks!  God you folks are quick :)

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this via regular expression:

```
<?php
function get($needle, $haystack, $before){
    preg_match($v="/.{".$before."}$needle/", $haystack, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}

echo get("hello", "I just want to say hello bobby!", 3);
```

Comment: What if `needle` contain special characters? I would suggest `preg_quote`, but regular expressions seem like overkill to begin with here :).